# Fix number of columns in Power BI Report Builder with TOP 10

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

[image: Sample Excel exported result from PowerBI Report Builder]

I need to display the Top 10 Columns based on value it works fine with other Key_sku, but some of Key_Sku has same qty, so when it gets top 10 it just adding another column because it is the same and it is under the Top 10. Can anyone help or suggest anything that can limit the number of columns in Power BI reportBuilder.